# Прописная или нет?

Tags: грамматика

"По Величайшему повелению" — верно ли писать с прописной?

Answer (score 1):

А что это за оборот?
По Высочайшему - с прописной, а эта форма мне неизвестна.
~~~
А, сообразил. Это возможно для высокопоставленного лица неимператорского звания. По отношению к Императору применять неправильно. Но в таком случае и причин для прописной нет никаких.